# Regex replace the substitution string

Tags: java, regex

Let's consider the following example:

```
String s = str.replaceAll("regexp", "$1");
```

Some languages allow us to specify `\U$1` in place of `$1` which converts matched groups with uppercase letters. How can I achieve the same using Java?

I know we can use `Pattern` class and get the group and convert it to uppercase, but that's not what I am looking for. I want to just change `$1` with something that gets the job done.

I have also tried:

```
String s = str.replaceAll("regexp", "$1".toUpperCase());
```

But it looks like `"$1".toUpperCase()` is `"$1"` and not the match. I confirmed it using:

```
String s = str.replaceAll("regexp", method("$1"));

// method declared as method()
private static String method(String s) {
    System.out.println(s); // prints "$1"
    return s;
}
```

Is it even allowed in Java?

**EDIT:**

```
String s = "abc";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(a)", "$1")); // should print "Abc"
```

***EDIT FOR POSSIBLE DUPE:***

I am not looking for way using `m.group()`, is it possible using something like `\U$1` in place of `$1` with `replaceAll()`

Comment: pls provide starting and ending result.

Comment: @Black.Jack I have updated the question

Comment: can't get the difference with toUppercase()

Comment: @Black.Jack Updated, It would make more sense now

Comment: sure, now it's clear thanks!!

Comment: @AyushGupta It will convert whole string to uppercase, I want to convert only the matched groups

Comment: problem is " but that's not what I am looking for" since that's the standard way to achieve that in java.

Comment: @Black.Jack I am asking if it is possible in Java because some languages allow to do so. And as much as I know about the regexp's and Java, `Pattern` is not a standard but helper

Comment: TLDR; no it's not possible

Comment: Here is the description of how `$...` is interpreted: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String). So, no, not possible.

Comment: To @Maroun, I know this won't be tagged to you but if you have read my question properly, you won't have marked this as a dupe.

Comment: @roundAbout I reopened, but please try to explain why it *doesn't* answer your question.

Comment: The question is fairly simple, I am looking for concise version of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java 9, we can provide a [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) to [`Matcher#replaceAll(Function<MatchResult,​String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)). It is more concise than other answers here. Eg:

```
Pattern.compile("regexp")
       .matcher(str)
       .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group().toUpperCase());
```

We can fully customize this behaviour since we have a hold on [`MatchResult`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html):

```
Pattern.compile("regexp")
       .matcher(str)
       .replaceAll(mr -> {
                String.format("%s %s", 
                              mr.group(1).toUpperCase),
                              mr.group(2).indent(4);
                   });
```

Answer (score 2):

`\\U` is not implemented in the java regex AFAIK and you can't do it with a regex as such (`.NET` has it IIRC). It's a bit verbose, but one way to do it would be:

```
    String test = "abc";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(a)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (m.find()) {
        String match = test.substring(m.start(1), m.end(1));
        m.appendReplacement(sb, match.toUpperCase());
    }

    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider StringUtils from Apache Commons.

This is an example:

```
String s = "abcad";

String replacer = "a";

System.out.println(StringUtils.replaceChars(s, replacer, replacer.toUpperCase()));//<--AbcAd
```

Pls also consider this avoids you to implement the algorythm that necessarily will be under the hood, and the fact the every jar library introduced in a project is basically a new weak point.

This is maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sure but the Op explicity doesn't want to use that approach.

Comment: If you did not notice, I posted the OP.

Comment: yes, if u prefer you coul put your strings inside replace chars. that would be one line. So ? less than one line?

Comment: I don't understand, show me the code. What I think you mean to create at least two `String` objects in that case right?

Comment: @roundAbout strings are immutable anyway, so you would create more instances anyway